# Integrality of polyhedra

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, polyhedra

1. Given two polyhedra in $H$ representation $P_1:Ax\leq b$ and $P_2:Bx\leq c$ which are integral are bounded when is their intersection also integral?
2. Given two polyhedra in $H$ representation $P_1:Ax\leq b$ and $P_2:Bx\leq c$ which are integral are bounded is there a polynomial time algorithm to find the $H$ representation of the integral polyhedron containing the integer points of their intersection where the polynomial time is parametrized by the minimum size of $H$  representation of the integral polyhedron container the intersection points?

Comment: Giving a useful exact criterion answering question 1 is probably hopeless...

Comment: for 2, it is not even clear why $H$ would be of size polynomial in the input.